# Parsing using Regex with 2 following format (CSV File)

Tags: regex, csv, format

I have a flat file  (CSV) with values separated by `"|"`, and i would like to convert all numbers with specific format "*1 234 567,89*" or "*1.123.456,89*" into "**1234567,89**"

In order to do that i created this regex rule:

```
(\|\ *)([0-9]{0,3})(\.|\ )?([0-9]{3})?(\.|\ )?([0-9]{3})?(,)?([0-9]{0,3})(-| )?(\|)
```

this works fine, except when 2 numbers are continus, for example:

```
| 9 450,000 |**9 809 100,000** | 1 890,000 |UN |
```

How can I correct that?

Comment: What language are you using? Can you process the output of the regexp?

Answer (score 0):

If the regex flavor you're using allow both lookarounds, I think this could be enough:

```
(?<=\d)(?: |\.)(?=\d)
```

And then replacing the matches by an empty string may be enough.
However, if you can't use them, you can still use

```
(\d)(?: |\.)(\d)
```

And then use the referenced groups (`$1$2` or `\1\2` depending on the flavor).

**Edit:**
To make sure not to replace dates:

```
(?<=\d)(?: |\.)(?=\d)(?=[ .\d]*,)
```

As you're using a csv file, your data are separated by `|` so that can work (as I don't have your entire data, I'm not sure).

Comment: At first thanks for your answer, however i cannot use your code as this one would convert Dateformat (such : 11.12.2012 into number as well)

Comment: You pretty much **have to** use a general expression if you don't want to have hugely long regex to match numbers higher and higher. I'm adding something else to check is there's a comma in the number (that would make sure not to replace dates).

Comment: Thanks, at the end i ll format the Date with '-' and this will solve the issue.