# Regex expression in order to convert Numbers

Tags: regex, csv, number-formatting

i want to convert a CSV File content converting the `12.345,67` or `12 345,67` numberformat into `12345,67`.
I followed the recomendation done in :
[Parsing using Regex with 2 following format (CSV File)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16146494/parsing-using-regex-with-2-following-format-csv-file)
with such regex expression:

```
(\d)(?: |\.)(\d)
```

and then i use groups `$1$2` as cleanresult 
which is working fine but as well modify the coments (`"Arome 12.233`" into "`Arome 12233`").
how can I do the change only if the number to convert starts with "`<blank>` or `|` (the CSV separator).

Examples:

```
|12 546,123 | AROME 53.213 | 52 321,15
|  2.546,123 | AROME 53 213 |152.321,15
```

Expecting result :

```
|12546,123 | AROME 53.213 | 52321,15
|  2546,123 | AROME 53 213 |152321,15
```

Comment: I am not expert in regex so putting just a comment, but you can use regex as \|\s*(\d)(?: |.)(\d)\s* this will modify your existing regex to read something like: Find string starting with | with possible spae and then digits. however during replacement you might want to add \| .. please try yourself that much :).

Comment: What language are you using? It would be easiest to just split the line first, then search/replace only in the elements of the resulting list that you want to change. The regex for that would be trivial.

Comment: @SumitGupta: I was trying something similar as your proposal but i do not have enough knowledge in Regex to explain the "should start with " " o "|" has to be a number and in a give line may appears several)

Comment: @alan This regex i expect to use it in a Pentaho Kettle transformation, and I would like to avoid splitting the fields before treating it, for lisibility of the transformation. Thank you any way

Comment: well, what I suggest is you put your data in database and then use SQL Regex to change all data to what you want, leave 100s of problem you face now :).

Comment: No, I meant 1) split it, 2) do the search/replace on the relevant elements, 3) join it back together with `|`

Answer (score 0):

Search for : `(?:[ |])(\d+)[ .](\d+)`
and replace with: `$1$2`

Comment: Thanks for your answer but your code do change the Comments as well and has another issue to remove some separators "|".

Answer (score 0):

You could try this regex:

```
((?:\|\s*|^)\d+)[ .](\d+)
```

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/sW2hA1)

Comment: Hi @Jerry, can you please help me another time, as I m using your RegEx until now and it s workign almost well.... ALMOST because I noticed that your expretion does not work for number biger als 999.999,99. Can you please tell me if thereis a way to remove the 1000 separators ("space" or ".") even if there are several (f.e.: 1.000.000 or 12 345 678,90) Thanks

Comment: @FredericRIsch Hi! Sorry for the late reply, I cut off from the internet because of exams. Do you know if the regex engine you use support the `\G` and `\K` anchors? If yes, you could maybe try this: `(?:\|\s*\d+|\G)\K[. ](\d{3}(?=[^A-Z]+(?:\||$)))`